# SQL Query to do grouping across a join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've an enrollment table containing student IDs, course IDs and teacher IDs.

```
___________________
| sID | cID | tID |
___________________
| 1   | 1   |  1  |
| 1   | 2   |  2  |
| 1   | 3   |  3  |
| 2   | 1   |  1  |
| 2   | 3   |  5  |
| 3   | 1   |  1  |
| 3   | 2   |  2  |
```

I would like to get a table that can tell me how many students are in each course with a given professor. In other words, I'd like this:

```
_____________________________
| cID | tID | numOfStudents |
____________________________
| 1   | 1   |       3       |
| 2   | 2   |       2       |
| 3   | 3   |       1       |
| 3   | 5   |       1       |
```

I've tried

```
SELECT cID, tID, count(sID) 
FROM enrollment 
GROUP BY tID
```

but this type of formula, with different combinations is not working for me. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `cid` to the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT cID, tID, count(*) 
FROM enrollment 
GROUP BY cid,tID
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ba429/1)</kbd>

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list
>   expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate
>   functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return
>   for an ungrouped column.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT cID, tID, count(sID) 
FROM enrollment 
GROUP BY 1,2